# Path of current working directory

Tags: path, lisp, clisp, cwd

I installed clisp on windows. I want to load a file but I can't. I do not know what is my current working directory. How can I see it and change it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ext:cd](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/dir-func.html#cd)

To display:

```
[1]> (ext:cd)
#P"/Users/pu/"
```

To change, add a path name or a string:

```
[3]> (ext:cd #P"/")
#P"/"
[3]> (ext:cd)
#P"/"

[3]> (ext:cd "/Users")
#P"/Users/"
[3]> (ext:cd)
#P"/Users/"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use *default-pathname-defaults*

```
(print *default-pathname-defaults*)
```

or *load-pathname*

```
(print *load-pathname*)
```